# Highcharts + set event click from options in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

I have an array options like this:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: '',
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Aantal keer gekozen',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        //valueSuffix: ' aantal keer gekozen'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                formatter: function() {
                    if (this.y === 0) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return this.y;
                    }
                }
            },
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: []
}
```

As you can see I don't do anything on the click function.

I create the highcharts in jQuery in a `foreach` (so I create multiple charts).

```
options.chart.renderTo = 'container' + index;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Now how can I add an event click like I did with `renderTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to read about closures in javascript - otherwise you add the same event for each chart.

Another solution is to create array of id's for charts and then use: `options.chart.events.click = function() { window.location.href = '/path/' + ids[index]; }`;

Comment: But if I have in my event this: " window.location.href = '/result/question/questionid/' + questionid; ", Then it won't be the same events is it?

Comment: So create simple array with qestion id's, and then use: `options.chart.events.redraw = function() { window.location.href = '/path/' + ids[index]; }`

Comment: But how do you set that it's a click function?

Comment: Ah, sorry! Instead of `redraw` use `click`, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click